# D3D12 Pipeline State Object use clarification

Tags: c++, directx, direct3d12

I'm working on my own D3D12 wrapper, and I'm in the beginning 'schema' phase. 
I understand the purpose of the PSO in a very simple rendering pipeline, but say I've multiple objects, meshes, models, whatever terminology works best, and I would like to use a different pixel shader for each,
for clarification, I would make multiple PSOs for each of these objects correct?

Sorry for the simple question, it's just a clarification I really need, thank you.

Comment: Yes, you need new PSO for every new pixel shader, doesn't matter if everything else is same

Comment: Thank you this helps clear things up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a distinct Pipeline State Object for *every unique combination* of all states:

- VS, PS, GS, etc. Shader Objects
- Blend, Depth, and Raster state
- Render Target format
- Number of render targets (MRT vs. 1)
- Sample count (MSAA vs. not)

In practice that means *at least* one PSO per unique material in your entire scene.

Comment: Thank you this makes understanding it alot easier!